# how to clear the TextView when reverting back to the same activity?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that displays an error message in the login page of my activity. I do not know how to clear its value when i come back to this activity. i used `editText.setText("")` for an EditText field. but when i tried to use this for my TextView it showed a `NullPointerException`
What could be used here ?

```
error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorPopUp);
```

Comment: onResume() is the right place to do stuff like this.

Comment: post a little more of your code here

Comment: your actual problem is when you come back to that activity textview reference gets null... is it correct?

Comment: Please provide the complete Activity code and layout as well.........

Comment: the complete activity may not be of any help.It will only occupy the space! 
protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        password.setText("");
        username.setText("");
       
    }
these are the EditText fields. I'm asking for a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  error.setText("");
}
```

Comment: In `onResume()` doesn't need to identify the textview?

Comment: as Chetna mentioned, she has initialized the `TextView`... and that instance can/will be used...

Comment: i did this. i set it in onResume() only, but that called a NullPointerException.

Comment: please post your code and logcat.... I guess issue is related to initialization of TextView.

Comment: Yes. I think so. @Chetna Just give `error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorPopUp);` to below of `onresume` with this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)